# Make Linq return object or null

Tags: linq

Is there a way to get the code below to return null if no objects are found?

```
var news = (from c in childs
where c.Name.ToLower().Contains("folder")
select c).First();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use FirstOrDefault() instead of First().  It will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You should call [`FirstOrDefault<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), which will return `default(T)` if there are no elements.

`default(T)` will be `null` for reference and nullable types, `0` for numeric types (`byte`, `int`, `double`, etc), and `new T()` for structures (which cannot be `null`)